# Bitmap.compress doesn't decrease image size

Tags: android, kotlin, bitmap, android-room, android-bitmap

I'm building an app that uses Room database and store images in it. I store the image as ByteArray and convert it with typeconverter to a Bitmap like this :

```
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromBitmap(bmp: Bitmap): ByteArray{
        val outputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, outputStream)
        return outputStream.toByteArray()
    }
    @TypeConverter
    fun toBitmap(bytes: ByteArray): Bitmap{
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.size)
    }
```

but I noticed that when I change the quality the size of the image does not change. What did I do wrong? and how can I decrease the size of the bitmap?

Comment: How do you know the image didn't change?

Comment: @cutiko from the app size and the byte array size

Comment: `I store the image as ByteArray` You store the image as jpg file.

Answer (score 0):

It did compress it.  The in memory Bitmap object takes 4 bytes per pixel.  It wrote it to the file system in a format that's copressed-  a JPG of 50% quality.  If you look at the size of the file, it will be smaller than `4*width*height` bytes small.

That doesn't mean that if you read it in and wrote it back to disk it will be smaller than the original file.  It probably won't be, unless you lower the quality setting in the new file compared to the old.  And its recommended not to do that anyway, as doing so will reencode the data with a lossy algorithm, which will degrade the image quality.

Answer (score 0):

A bitmap is pretty much just a stream of data for `width * height` pixels, where each pixel is represented by a fixed number of bytes [depending on the colour depth](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config#summary). You can save that as a JPEG, and get *storage* compression, but once you load it back in **as a bitmap** you need the same number of bytes for the same number of pixels. The byte array will be the same length.

That's just how an image is represented. You won't get any bitmap size savings unless you shrink the image (fewer pixels to represent) or lower the colour depth (fewer bytes per pixel). Using stronger JPEG compression will make the *file* smaller and lose detail, but it still represents the same number of pixels when loaded as a bitmap. It'll just look worse!

Answer (score 0):

> What did I do wrong?

You are probably not checking the actual data that is stored.

> and how can I decrease the size of the bitmap?

You probably have done so.

Here's an example that shows how you can programmatically see the length of the stored data.

First the @Entity class **TestTable** :-

```
@Entity
data class TestTable(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Long? = null,
    val image: Bitmap
)
```

The image column is a BitMap so the TypeConverters, as per the code in the question, ate located in the class **Converters**.

The @Dao used for the demo is **AllDao** :-

```
@Dao
abstract class AllDao {

    @Insert
    abstract fun insert(testTable: TestTable): Long

    @Query("SELECT 'Image length is :-'||length(image)||' for row with  ID '||id FROM TestTable")
    abstract fun getStoredImageLlength(): List<String>
}
```

- Note the query, this will extract the actual length of the data as stored in the database using the in-built [SQLite length function](https://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#length).

The @Database class **TheDatabase** is pretty standard/simple (other than allowing use of the main thread (for brevity/convenience)) :-

```
@Database(entities = [TestTable::class],version = 1)
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getAllDao(): AllDao

    companion object {
        private var instance: TheDatabase? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context): TheDatabase {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase::class.java,"thedatabase.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as TheDatabase
        }
    }
}
```

Last is an invoking activity that inserts a row into the TestTable and then extracts the length reporting the length of the bitmap and the length of the compressed and therefore stored data :-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDao
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this);
        dao = db.getAllDao();

        val i = this.assets.open("sample.jpg")
        val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(i)
        dao.insert(TestTable(image = bitmap))
        for(s: String in dao.getStoredImageLlength()) {
            Log.d("DBINFO","Bitmap Length = ${bitmap.byteCount} $s")
        }
    }
}
```

The result is :-

```
D/DBINFO: Bitmap Length = 19660800 Image length is :-63685 for row with  ID 1
```

An alternative way could be to utilise Android Studio's App Inspector (Database Inspector) to view the database and then run a query e.g. (as for the above database) :-

[image]